# i need to know which of my url is indexed on google

Tags: c#

some of my website urls are duplicated.
i need to know which of them are indexed by google
i need some function in c# to know which of my url is indexed.

Comment: What are you going to *do* about it, even if you manage to find out?

Comment: Voted to move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google's search you can type:
site:yourdomain

And it will show you the results. you can use the Google Custom Search API programmatically to do this.
http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

It returns JSON results that you can convert into C# objects using the DataContractSerializer.

You'll need to sign up for an API key if you go this route.

**Edit**
As for Html Agility Pack, I have a blog post that shows how you can extract the links on a page

[Finding links on a Web page](http://www.matlus.com/finding-links-on-a-web-page)